# pySerial read() only reads up to 116 characters? Is this an issue with PythonSerial or the PLC I'm connecting to?

Tags: python, pyserial

I am writing a command to my PLC to read 50 registers each register returning 4 characters of information (and around 8 characters for other information). For some reason though, the most I can read is 27 registers using

```
datarecv = ser.read(116)
```

where normally I'd wish to use  ser.read(208) but this freezes up the program for some reason. Now a work around that I use is to do 2 separate reads one reading 26 registers and the other reading 24. What is the reason for the limit above and is it possible to get all the information in one read?

Comment: Have you confirmed that the PLC is trying to send you 208 bytes?

Answer (score 0):

How long does it take to read all registers when you use 2 separate reads?

To debug the problem you may try the following:

1) Setup reasonable timeout for the connection, let's say 10 seconds or whatever it takes

```
 ser = serial.Serial(comDev, 115200, timeout=10)
```

2) Write your command and don't `flush` anything

2) Read from serial character by character and, checking `buffer`, see where it hangs up (it shouldn't if your PCL doesn't need additional writes or whatever else to real all registers)

```
buffer = []
while 1: 
    ch = self.ser.read()
    buffer.append(ch)
    print buffer
```